# Appending key : value data onto MySQL table

Tags: mysql

Excuse my ignorance, but is there a tidy way to automatically join or append meta values (set as temporary columns by key) from one table to another?

**Table items**
ID (int)
title (varchar 255)
content  (longtext)

**Table meta**
ID (int)
item_id (int)
key (varchar 255)
value (longtext)

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do a generic query like

`SELECT * FROM items`

and have the output as

`item.ID  item.title          item.content          metakey1         metakey2
1        Listing Title       Listing content       meta_val1        meta_val2
2        Another Title       Listing content       meta_val1        meta_val2`

Comment: Have you tried key() function or array_keys() ?

Comment: I would like to do this inside a single SQL query if possible...

Comment: my suggestion: the day I gave up trying to do everything in one single query, my life started to work well again. I'm on a smartphone right now so can't be more specific to a solution or try things out.

Comment: @RichardDenton, did my answer below help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your data in XML format and use [MySQL XML Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/xml-functions.html) to extract them.

Example:

```
create table items (id int, title varchar(100), content longtext);
create table meta (id int, item_id int, metadata varchar(100));
insert into items values (1, 'test item1', 'some content');
insert into meta values (1, 1, '<key1>value1</key1><key2>value2</key2>');

select 
  i.id, i.title, i.content, 
  extractvalue(m.metadata, '//key1[$1]') as key1, 
  extractvalue(m.metadata, '//key2[$1]') as key2 
from items i 
inner join meta m on i.id = m.item_id;

+------+------------+--------------+--------+--------+
| id   | title      | content      | key1   | key2   |
+------+------------+--------------+--------+--------+
|    1 | test item1 | some content | value1 | value2 |
+------+------------+--------------+--------+--------+
```

You can create a view called items_with_metadata and then call `select * from items_with_metadata` to get the kind of output you desire.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want, but it sound like the [mysql view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/views.html) behaviour.

That'll allow you to create virtual table with on-the-fly generated field.

To explain a bit : you make a SELECT statement and tell MySql to use it as a Table.